# Adding an api route to a polymer app

Tags: javascript, express, polymer

I'm working on a polymer application, I want to include some data from a simple rest API, but due to CORS I think to encapsulate this in a simple server-side express route.

Whenever I attempt to GET my new route, it loads the polymer defined 404 page and in console I can see I get sent to /src/latestValues, so I am thinking that the polymer work here is intercepting my request, perhaps?

How can I add an express route to my application where i can use node-rest-client to pull some external data into my pages?

```
/*eslint-env node*/

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// node.js starter application for Bluemix
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// This application uses express as its web server
// for more info, see: http://expressjs.com
var express = require('express');

// cfenv provides access to your Cloud Foundry environment
// for more info, see: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cfenv
var cfenv = require('cfenv');

// create a new express server
var app = express();

// serve the files out of ./public as our main files
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/build/es6-bundled'));

// get the app environment from Cloud Foundry
var appEnv = cfenv.getAppEnv();

// REST client for latest values:
var Client = require('node-rest-client').Client;
var client = new Client();
client.registerMethod("xxx", "xxx", "GET");

// Return a page
app.get('/latestValues', function(req, res){

  client.methods.getVanValues(function (data, response) {

    var readings2 = [
      data
    ]

    res.send(readings2);
});
});

// Render index.html on the main page, specify the root
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile("index.html", {root: '.'});
  });

// start server on the specified port and binding host
app.listen(appEnv.port, '0.0.0.0', function() {
  // print a message when the server starts listening
  console.log("server starting on " + appEnv.url);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think i resolved the issue, for reasons beyond my current knowledge, in Chrome if i try to access a different route in the same hostname it expects an app, it adds the /src/ to the path and finds nothing, the route works fine via rest client so i think my problem is resolved and i can start using that data in my app, although i did make some changes to app.js too, so i include it here for completeness:

```
/*eslint-env node*/

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// node.js starter application for Bluemix
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// This application uses express as its web server
// for more info, see: http://expressjs.com
var express = require('express');

// cfenv provides access to your Cloud Foundry environment
// for more info, see: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cfenv
var cfenv = require('cfenv');

// create a new express server
var app = express();

// serve the files out of ./public as our main files
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/build/es6-bundled'));

// get the app environment from Cloud Foundry
var appEnv = cfenv.getAppEnv();

// Return a page
app.get('/latestValues', function(req, res){

  // REST client for latest values:
  var Client = require('node-rest-client').Client;
  var client = new Client();
  client.registerMethod("xxx", "xxx", "GET");

  client.methods.getVanValues(function (data, response) {

    var readings2 = [
      data
    ]
    res.status(200).send(readings2);
  });
});

// Render index.html on the main page, specify the root
app.get('*', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile("index.html", {root: './'});
  });

// start server on the specified port and binding host
app.listen(appEnv.port, '0.0.0.0', function() {
  // print a message when the server starts listening
  console.log("server starting on " + appEnv.url);
});
```